# Not able to find opencv after inporting it

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, conda

I am trying to install libraries in a conda environment and then run a ipynb. I created my environment and install the libraries, i import them but i get the error

```
 ----> 1 img = cv.imread('data/train/01.jpg')
      2 result=extrage_careu(img)
      3 show_image('img',result)

NameError: name 'cv' is not defined
```

I am in the right env: (TestEnv) D:\Computer Vision\Proiect Cava>
I set the kernel for the project : anaconda\TestEnv\python.exe
In this folder: D:\Anaconda\envs\TestEnv\Lib\site-packages i can find the cv2 library among others

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
import os
import os
os.sys.path
```

the output is this

```
`'d:\\Computer Vision\\Proiect Cava',
 'd:\\Anaconda\\envs\\TestEnv\\python38.zip',
 'd:\\Anaconda\\envs\\TestEnv\\DLLs',
 'd:\\Anaconda\\envs\\TestEnv\\lib',
 'd:\\Anaconda\\envs\\TestEnv',
 '',
 'd:\\Anaconda\\envs\\TestEnv\\lib\\site-packages',
 'd:\\Anaconda\\envs\\TestEnv\\lib\\site-packages\\win32',
 'd:\\Anaconda\\envs\\TestEnv\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib',
 'd:\\Anaconda\\envs\\TestEnv\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin']`
```

I tried everything i found online

Comment: Are you running the import in the same cell as the code? If not, can you try that?

Comment: i tried to run them in the same cell. If i run the cells in the browser after i start the server with jupyter notebook is works fine but in the visual studio code it is not able to find the libraries